# How to open a PDF file just after creating it?

Tags: java, fileoutputstream, dynamic-reports

I want to Flush FileInputStream instance just after creating a pdf file.

I am using dynamic reports to export the report to pdf

I won't post the whole code. Only the important part

```
JasperReportBuilder report = DynamicReports.report();//a new report
    File path= new File("/home/kunal/Medicam reports/Sale Report");
                String pdfreport = String.valueOf(dateformat.format(date));
                if(!path.exists())
                {
                    path.mkdirs();
                    report.toPdf(new FileOutputStream(path+"/"+pdfreport+".pdf"));

                }
                else
                {
                    report.toPdf(new FileOutputStream(path+"/"+pdfreport+".pdf"));

                }

                File generatedfile = new File("/home/kunal/Medicam reports/Sale Report/"+pdfreport+".pdf");
                if(generatedfile.exists())
                {
                    if(Desktop.isDesktopSupported())
                    {
                        Desktop.getDesktop().open(generatedfile);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        System.out.println("Not Supported by your desktop");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println("File does not Exists");
                }
```

Whenever I run the above code the else part gets executed as `"File does not exists"`

The file is generated but when I try to read the newly generated file the `generatedfile.exists()` condition fails

Answer (score 0):

use report.show() method,it instantly opens the pdf after the compilation is successful.